# Can the homepage show questions most recently asked/answered, not modified?

Tags: feature-request

When I logged in this morning, nearly the entire front page was full of questions that had been actually asked 2 or 3 years ago. They seem to have flagged by the system as "active" because someone made edits to the question or answer sometime in the past few hours.  For the most part, the edits were simple formatting or typo-corrections.

Is there any way to see a list of just the most recently asked or answered questions on the homepage, and ignore questions that were simply modified recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the settings on the front page, but here is a search you can use to see all questions and answers, with the most recent ones first: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22%22. I don't think the search page notifies you if new questions or answers are posted.

If you only care about new questions (not new answers), you can go to the [Questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) page and click on [newest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). That page will notify you of newly asked questions, like the front page does.

If you only want to see new answers, you can use this search: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa

Comment: Another thing you can do is to **click on the big "Questions" button at the top and sort them by "newest"**. This gives you a list of all *questions* with the most recently asked at the top, and like the front page, it updates with a little "1 question with new activity" notice every time a new question is asked. Maybe you could add this to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just to the right of the site logo is a "Questions" button that takes you to a page with several ways to sort questions, the default is most recently asked.

[image: Questions button]